# Solution to problem question in Python to distribute a number of items among a team

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I recently stumbled upon a problem-solving question in an online coding platform.

A Manager would like to pass out chocolates to his employees. Actually passing out chocolates isn't easy. Each employee squad has a strict seniority ranking which must be respected - or else the employees will revolt.

There are 4 key rules which you must follow in order to avoid a revolt:

```
1. The most junior employee (with the least seniority) gets exactly 1 chocolate.  (There will always be at least 1 employee on a team.)
2. An employee will revolt if the person who ranks immediately above them gets more than double the number of chocolates as they do.
3. An employee will revolt if the amount of chocolates given to their next two subordinates combined is more than the number of chocolates they get.  (Note that the two most junior employees won't have two subordinates, so this rule doesn't apply to them.  The 2nd most junior employee would require at least as many chocolates as the most junior employee.)
4. You can always find more employees to pay - the Manager has plenty of employees.  If there is enough chocolate leftover such that another employee could be added as the most senior while obeying the other rules, you must always add and pay that employee.
```

Note that you may not be able to hand out all the chocolates. A single LAMB cannot be subdivided. That is, all henchmen must get a positive integer number of chocolates.

Write a function called solution(total_chocolates), where total_ chocolates is the integer number of chocolates in the handout you are trying to divide. It should return an integer which represents the difference between the minimum and the maximum number of employees who can share the chocolates (that is, being as generous as possible to those you pay and as stingy as possible, respectively) while still obeying all of the above rules to avoid a revolt.  For instance, if you had 10  chocolates and were as generous as possible, you could only pay 3 employees (1, 2, and 4  chocolates, in order of ascending seniority), whereas if you were as stingy as possible, you could pay 4 employees (1, 1, 2, and 3  chocolates). Therefore, solution(10) should return 4-3 = 1.

To keep things interesting, the Manager varies the sizes of the chocolate payouts. You can expect total_chocolates to always be a positive integer less than 1 billion (10 ^ 9).

I came up with the following solution:

```
def solution(total_chocolates):

    if not isinstance(total_chocolates, int) or total_lambs<=1 or total_lambs >= 1000000000: 
        return 0

    else:
        F1=[1,1]
        F2=[1]

        for i in range(1,total_chocolates):

            if sum(F1) < total_chocolates:
                F1.append(F1[-1]+F1[-2])    #fibonacci series from 1
            if sum(F1) > total_chocolates:
                F1.pop()

            LEN_F1 = len(F1)

            if sum(F2) < total_chocolates:
                F2.append(F2[-1] * 2)      #1,2,4,8,16.. series
            if sum(F2) > total_chocolates:
                F2.pop()       

            LEN_F2 = len(F2)


        return (LEN_F1-LEN_F2)
```

I am getting the right answer but it still failed in a hidden test case. I would appreciate it if someone could help me find where the issue is?

Comment: can it be a timeout or is it an improper value ?
I hint that computing the general term for fibo or the geo sequence would allow to skip that timeout part

Comment: @grodzi Yes. It is possible. I will give it a go.

Comment: think this can be solved math way, given a NUM, 1. NUM >=  1+2+4+8..2^n                 2. NUM >=  1+1+2+3+5..FIBONACCI(m). what is the diff m-n,      now expression 1 = 2^(n+1) -1,   expression 2 equals FIB(m+2) - 1,  I think m, n can be extracted in few steps, and for big number it will be more officiant